# Recent contacts fetching recent call logs gives error

Tags: android, cursor, android-contentprovider, contactscontract

I have an application which shows recent contacts of phone.
so i used the below code to fetch recent contacts but when i tried to run it gives me following error.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from
>   CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before
>   accessing data from it.

Here is my recent contacts fetching code:

```
ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getContentResolver();

    String[] projection = new String[] {ContactsContract.Contacts._ID}; // you can add more fields you need here
    int oneDay = ( 1000 *3600 * 24);
    long last24h = (System.currentTimeMillis() - oneDay);

   Cursor cur=cr.query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,null);
    String phone = null;
    String emailContact = null;
    String image_uri;
    Bitmap bitmap;


    if (cur.getCount() > 0)
    {
        while (cur.moveToNext())
        {
            String id = cur.getString(cur
                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String name = cur
                    .getString(cur
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

            image_uri = cur
                    .getString(cur
                              .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI));
            if (Integer
                    .parseInt(cur.getString(cur
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0)
            {

                Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                + " = ?", new String[]{id}, null);
                while (pCur.moveToNext())
                {
                    phone = pCur
                            .getString(pCur
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    // contactid=pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));

                   /* phonenumber.add(pCur
                            .getString(pCur
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));`*/

                }
                pCur.close();


                Cursor emailCur = cr.query
                        (
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
                                null,
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID
                                        + " = ?", new String[]{id}, null);

                while (emailCur.moveToNext())
                {
                    emailContact = emailCur
                            .getString(emailCur
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));

                    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(emailContact)||emailContact.equalsIgnoreCase(null)||emailContact.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                    {
                        emailContact="";

                    }

                    else
                    {

                    }
                  /*  emailType = emailCur
                            .getString(emailCur
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE));*/
                }
                emailCur.close();
            }

            if (image_uri != null)
            {
                System.out.println(Uri.parse(image_uri));
                try
                {
                    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media
                            .getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(),
                                    Uri.parse(image_uri));
                    System.out.println(bitmap);

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            recent_list.add(new Contacts(name, phone, image_uri,emailContact));
            emailContact="";
            phone="";
        }
        cur.close();
    }
    else
    {
        noContact.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        search_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Comment: did you give the necessary permissions? and at which line are you getting the exception?

Comment: yes i  gave all the required permissions

Comment: i want recent call logs on phone

Comment: are you getting the exception at this line `Cursor cur=cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, ContactsContract.Contacts.LAST_TIME_CONTACTED+">"+last24h , null,null);`?

Comment: yes i am getting error on the specified line check the code again please

Comment: did you add both `READ_CONTACTS` and `WRITE_CONTACTS` permissions?

Comment: yes i gave all the necessary permissions'

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access fields in the cursor that were not specified in the projection, that's not possible.

The projection needs to contain all the fields you'll need.

HOWEVER, you can't access Contact fields from the Call Log table.

Just like I recently answered your other question here: [How to fetch recent and favourite contacts in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43715236/how-to-fetch-recent-and-favourite-contacts-in-android)